# Favicon not visible when debugging but it does show up when deploying to sever

Tags: asp.net, favicon

Our favicon won't show up while debugging, though it does show up when it has been deployed to a server. what could cause this behavior?

the code we use is:

```
 <head>
     <title>Our Application Name</title>
     <link rel="icon" 
       type="image/x-icon"
      href="favicon.ico"/> 
 </head>
```

the image is located in our root so it should have no problem finding it.

**Edit**

This is only when debugging in IE9, debugging in chrome or firefox shows the ico correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following:

the code was in the index page. but when debugging i put the start up page as the log on page.
basically it didn't go past to the index page and skipped it.

when on the server it passes the index page and gets redirected to the logon page. which is why i saw it on the server but not locally.

The reason why i thought it worked on all browsers but IE is the same really. i went to the index page without going to the log-on page.

It's more of a mistake of mine, but i hope people with the same mistake will find out what they're doing wrong faster now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to debug your code with fiddler to see the exact problem.
There you'll see if the URL is correct, or if you have any problem with privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, fiddler indeed sais there's a 404 error with the favicon.ico path. though it seems to be correct. i'll get back to you if i find out why it's giving a file not found exception.

Comment: The 404 error was caused by moving the file around to try and get it to show. it wasn't the root of the problem. but fiddler is a handy tool! i've found the answer and posting it now.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to review. Are you sure favicon.ico is in your bin folder? Maybe, you have the icon in your project but it's not present in the bin\debug folder.